# Hide popup behind the existed browser

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension

I want to use Google sign-in with Chrome Extension. The Google sign-in popup actually appears, but it's hidden behind the existing browser, which is not good for usability.

I don't know how to bring it to the forefront, but it would be nice if I could set the popup to focus.

```
const bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
bgPage?.signInWithPopup()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the extension's behavior and the fact it is inside a  highlighted window. A workaround is to open a new tab that lets the user log in directly rather than a popup and simply hand the re-auth and session token back to the extension.